# BizTalk installation issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Getting below error while installing BizTalk server 2013 R2 in Windows 10.
SQL server 2014 is available in server

Under Groups while installation

> Message:[DBNETLIB}[Connection open(SEDoClientHandshake()).]SSL SECURITY ERROR

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is not a supported operating system for BizTalk 2013 R2.

[Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2013-and-2013-r2#BKMK_SoftRequirements)

> **BizTalk Server 2013 R2**
> Windows Server 2012 R2
> Windows Server 2012
> Windows 8.1
> Windows 7 SP1